# Characteristics of the surviving mice Experiment

Tags: regression, probability, correlation, pearson-r

Could someone help me sort through my experiment? I had a couple classes in statistics several years ago and I've let most of it slip.
Could someone provide statistical insight a better way to analyze the data.

i have a data set with what we'll say is mice which were given a treatment and many of them died, some survived and others recovered. I'm studying the characteristics of the survivors and potentially recovered. There were 76 mice as part of the experiment. i noticed that the mice were sometimes from the same genes so i kept created a separate excel sheet for the maximum survival rate for each genus and there were 27 mice left. i further filtered the data set by family taking the maximum survivor and discarding the rest and created a sheet with 13 mice in it.
I'm analyzing the characteristics of each mice and using the t test and correl function of excel. 
I found this webpage 
http://vassarstats.net/rsig.html
and so I highlighted all the correlations which had a p value < than .05 as significant
then I ran a paired 1 tail t test and found that a few samples with good correlations had a p value greater than .05 and i highlighted those results. 
the main data set with 76 mice my maximum correlation was 26% to survival rate 
for the genus data set with 27 mice the maximum correlation was 38% 
and for the family data set with 13 mice in it the maximum correlation was 56%.

I know that correlations are frowned on in scientific publications so I ran the ttest too but I don't think I did it correctly.

There were very few characteristics that had a ttest p value > .05 in the general data set and genus data set.
in the main data set with 76 mice two characteristics had p=.156 and .131 but they don't match the correlations at all. in the genus data set the ttest seems to match the correlations better. there is 4 characteristics with p = .098, .38, .05 and .11 and finally in the family data set there are a whopping 62 with p>.05.

Thank you for reading my question and helping :)

Edit:
I ran the data with pearson's correlation and it came out similar. 
I also noticed earlier in the data set that some mice had multiple samples take from them and I combined those results. I also ran the regression function from the data analysis on a couple of samples and the probability of observation was .04 and .02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found ANOVA which gives a significance that replaces the t test